# How to write in the end of a file using stream aws s3 php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm using the code above for writing in a file :

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret',
    )
)); 
$client->registerStreamWrapper();
$stream = fopen("s3://bucket-name/files/filename.txt", 'w');
fwrite($stream, $message);
fclose($stream);
```

it works , but i need to write at the end of the file conserving content already writed... i thought using '**w+**' was the solution , but noo , 
plz how can i do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs you should use `a`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Sure, just update me if it helped

Comment: thanks a lot , just a point to add is that it doesn't accept a+ or w+.

Comment: Glad it helped you, i'll write it as an answer, please approve it after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the php manual ([`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)):

> Mode W
>
> Open for writing only; place the file pointer **at the beginning**
> of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
> exist, attempt to create it.

So in case you'd like to start writing at the end of the file,
you should use mode **a**.

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file.
> If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.